# I have 2 database files in the Directory folder and I want for the user to select which he wants to open

Tags: ios, sqlite, database-connection, restore

I am using SQLite3 and iOS.

There is a database "2012" in my resources folder. I made a backup of it (named 2013) in my app's directory folder, so in there, there are the databases 2012 and 2013 with the same structure.

I have made a view controller where the user can select which database he wants to open 2012 or 2013.

How can I pass the "2013" NSString to the connect method?

```
-(void)connect
{
NSLog(@"%c",restore); // restore is a BOOL that becomes "YES" when i click the button for restore

if (restore  == YES)
{
    databaseName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.db",currentYear];
}
else
{
    databaseName = @"2012.db";
}
NSLog(@"Database name is: %@",databaseName);

// Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

NSLog(@"Database path is: %@",databasePath);

[self checkAndCreateDatabase];
```

}

and I am trying to send the year value to connect:

```
NSString *year = restoreYear.text;
DatabaseDB *databaseDB = [[DatabaseDB alloc]init];
databaseDB.currentYear = year; //in DatabaseDB i have created property for current year and restore
databaseDB.restore = YES;
```

Comment: So this is a question about how to pass parameters to Objective-C methods?

Comment: No, I want to pass this value just for one time. I can't figure out how this could be.
-(void) connect:(NSString *)_name is the right? If you think about it, every time that i want execute a query, i must call [database connect:name]??

Comment: By "Directory folder" you mean "Documents folder""?

Answer (score 0):

A restore function says  you want to go back to a point in time that a snapshot was taken.  If this is what you really want, all you need to do is copy the backed up database to the name of the "active" db.  Optionally you could first rename your active copy so that you can undo the restore.